# SSRS report cannot connect to SSAS cube once deployed

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, reporting-services, ssas, ssrs-2012

I have an SSRS report that connects to an cube using a shared SSAS data source with integrated security. In visual studio the report works fine and connects successfully. Once I deploy it to the report server (sharepoint 2013 integrated/sql 2012) then it won't work and gives an access denied error.

[image]

My user is an admin on the SSAS instance so security is not the issue. Can connect fine with ssrs in visual studio, excel, ssms. Only once the report is deployed and run in sharepoint it doesn't work. Similar error if I go to the data source in sharepoint and try to test the connection.

[image]

Comment: Are you deploying datasource too?

Comment: It's already deployed. I did deploy it again just to make sure.

Comment: Go to SSRS site and open datasource properties, check the credentials used for connection. Actually these credentials will be used to connect to SSAS.

Comment: Yes that is what my second screenshot is. I want it to use Windows authentication (integrated) because I don't want everyone to be able to access it, but this is not working for some reason.

Comment: I ended up doing stored credentials, and then setting security in sharepoint on the report and data source. Not sure if this is a better solution or not, but it works. I would still be interested to figure out why the integrated security is failing just once deployed to sharepoint, as this should work as well.

Comment: That's a workaround I used too, I faced the same issue it is known as _double-hop_ errors. Check [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/rob/archive/2011/11/23/enabling-kerberos-authentication-for-reporting-services.aspx)

Comment: I was wondering if that was the issue. However my sharepoint and sql server are on the same server. I still have the same issue if I remote into the server and try and run the report in IE on the server. Wouldn't that mean it is something else, or could double hop still be the problem?

Comment: Have you tried browsing the cube while impersonating as that user? That should get you somewhere.

Comment: How would that help me figure it out? I have a normal domain user with a read only role on the cube, and an SSAS sysadmin, that is a domain admin as well. Both can browse the cube fine with ssrs in visual studio, excel, and ssms. So security isn't the issue. Something to do with connecting to the source from Sharepoint SSRS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem was that even though my user had permissions. Using integrated security causes a double hop problem (computer ->report server -> db server) in order to authenticate. By using stored credentials on the report server is solves the double hop problem (report server -> db server).